# Login to dropbox using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am coding a simple python program which involves oauth authrization. I want to automate the process of logging into the dropbox account. Here is my code.

```
def authorize():
    app_key = '###'
    app_secret = '###'

    flow = dropbox.client.DropboxOAuth2FlowNoRedirect(app_key, app_secret)
    authorize_url = flow.start()
    if True:
        driver=webdriver.Firefox()#depends on your browser

        driver.get(authorize_url)
        email=WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "login_email")))


        email.send_keys("###")
        login=driver.find_element_by_class_name("login-button button-primary")
        login.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        accept= WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "allow_access")))
        accept.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
            #accept.click()
        code1= WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "auth-code")))
        code=code1.get_attribute("innerHTML")


        driver.quit()
        dropboxfile.authorized=True
```

The code returns exception stating that it did not find any element with name `login_email`. But the element exists. I have tried other methods like `find_element_by_class_name`, `find_element_by_id` but to no avail.

Comment: The are two common and most popular reasons for that: 1. the content is dynamically formed and you need to wait for the elements to show up (you are already doing it) 2. there is an iframe element containing the element and you need to switch to it before making a search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found the solution to the problem. I used xpath to locate different elements.

```
def authorize():
    app_key = '###'
    app_secret = '###'
    try:
        flow = dropbox.client.DropboxOAuth2FlowNoRedirect(app_key, app_secret)
        authorize_url = flow.start()
    except:
        print "No internet connection"
        return
    try:
        driver=webdriver.Firefox()#depends on your browser
        driver.get(authorize_url)
        (WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[@class="text-input-input autofocus"]')))).send_keys(account.dname)
        (WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[@class="password-input text-input-input"]')))).send_keys(account.dpass)
        (WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[@type="submit"]')))).click()
        (WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "allow_access")))).click()
        code1= WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "auth-code")))
        code=code1.get_attribute("innerHTML")
        driver.quit()
        dropboxfile.authorized=True
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI: I didnt found on this page IDs that you write in the code. Try to use the following steps for successful auth.

1. Create browser instance, change url to dropbox.com, etc
2. Click on element with Id "sign-in"
3. wait for ajax/wait half second / wait for element "sign-in" will be visible
4. Find by name element "sign-in" and SendKeys needed
5. Find by name element "login_password" and SendKeys needed

and after you have 2 choises:

5.1 Find element by xpath "//div[text()='Sign in']/parent::button" and click on it

5.2 Send to "login_password" Enter key

That's all. Sorry that without code, I don't know python.